# Google Calendar API Invalid value for start-min parameter

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I am using the exact examples from the Google Calendar API in C#:
            string calendarURI = this.CalendarURI.Text;
            string userName =    this.UserName.Text;
            string passWord =    this.Password.Text;

```
        this.entryList = new ArrayList(50); 
        ArrayList dates = new ArrayList(50); 
        EventQuery query = new EventQuery();
        CalendarService service = new CalendarService("CalendarSampleApp");

        if (userName != null && userName.Length > 0)
        {
            service.setUserCredentials(userName, passWord);
        }

        // only get event's for today - 1 month until today + 1 year

        query.Uri = new Uri(calendarURI);

        query.StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-28); 
        query.EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6);


        EventFeed calFeed = service.Query(query) as EventFeed;
        Console.WriteLine(query.Uri);
```

This is copied from the examples, but when I run it I get:

> Execution of request failed: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full?start-min=2010-11-19T23:58:20+01:00&start-max=2011-06-17T23:58:20+02:00

Which is the message

> Invalid value for start-min parameter: 2010-11-19T23:58:20 01:00

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem solved itself, now I don't get that error anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You're not correctly URL encoding the plus sign in the datetime and a `+` represents a space in a URL...

Replace the plus with its url-encoded equivalent `%2B` and it all works fine...

> http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full?start-min=2010-11-19T23:58:20%2B01:00&start-max=2011-06-17T23:58:20%2B02:00

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug in google's example code or your implementation of it - The error doesn't occur with negative timezones as a `-` doesn't require url-encoding.

Comment: And how will I do this? the EventQuery object will parse the parameter for me, then it will query itself, but I cannot manipulate this data...